# How can I use Java to read a file

Tags: java, file, object, youtube, java.util.scanner

So I have this piece of code in which I want to allow the user to enter in a String of any length and it encrypts the code. To make this more than a basic project, I thought it would be cool to have a 'save' feature where the user can pickup from later on.
The problem arises here. I was going through Youtube and through a video where I learned how to create a file and write to a file. When I went to the part where I read the file (load) I saw that I need to create a variable for every single character in the file. As I will not know how many variables to make, I am stuck.
In his code (I will display it) he uses a `while` loop to loop through the contents of the file and using a variables he prints out its contents. My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;  
public class Sep {
    private Formatter x;
    public void openfile () {
        try {
            x = new Formatter("Gogo.txt");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("You have an error mate!!");
        }
    }
    public void addStuff() {
        x.format("%s%s%s%s", "Gogo will return!!", "Stronger than ever!!", "Faster than can be seen!!", "And he is out for blood...");
        }
    public void closeFile () {
        x.close();
    }
}
```

As the user will be entering whatever he wants, I have no bloody clue on how many variables to make.
The youtuber has this:

```
import java.util.*;


public class Sep {
    private Formatter g;
    private Scanner x;
    public void openfile () {
        try {
            g = new Formatter("Gogo.txt");
            x = new Scanner(new File("gogo.txt"));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("You have an error mate!!");
        }
    }
    public void addStuff() {
        g.format("%s%s%s%s", "Gogo will return!!", "Stronger than ever!!", "Faster than can be seen!!", "And he is out for blood...");
        }
    public void readFile() {
        while(x.hasNext()) {
            String a = x.next();
            String b = x.next();
            String c = x.next();
            System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", a,b,c);
        }
    public void closeFile () {
        x.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question?

Comment: It would probably help to know what/how you need to use the characters. Loading an entire file of unknown size is probably a bad way to go, for instance if you only use _N_ consecutive characters at time you shouldn't load more.

Comment: It is a bad idea to use multiple next() with one hasNext()...

Comment: It's also a bad idea to use `next()` when you need to operate on characters. Users will be ticked off if they decrypt their file and find all the white-space missing.

Comment: It's also a bad idea to follow some random youtuber's advice, instead of reading [proper tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) which explain in depth how things work. I fear that watching a youtube video may give you a false idea that programming is *easy*, although that idea usually disappears quite quickly.

Comment: `Youtube` tag is hurt and shouts **use me only when you need me.**

Comment: If you're running in Windows, `new Formatter("Gogo.txt")` and `new Scanner(new File("gogo.txt"))` are reading and writing the same file, which is going to cause problems.  Follow Kayaman's advice and read the tutorials.

Comment: Consider using [`java.io.FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) instead of `Scanner`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
al.add(x.next);//this is in while loop
```

Then just print out the ArrayList:

```
foreach(String s : al)
    System.out.printf("%s\n", s);
```